# Decrypting using AES-256

Tags: c#, php, encryption, aes

So... I've been using a php function to encrypt data on my server. I have more than 2000 rows already encrypted. I am now making a c# application that connect to my mysql server and retrieve or input new data. (We both have website app and a local application that we need to use).

For my php function, I found this one on the net and it does the job to encrypt / decrypt stuff easily.

```
     function encryption( $string, $action ) {
        // you may change these values to your own
        $secret_key = 'thisismykey_key';
        $secret_iv = 'thisismyiv_iv';

        $output = false;
        $encrypt_method = "AES-256-CBC";
        $key = hash( 'sha256', $secret_key );
        $iv = substr( hash( 'sha256', $secret_iv ), 0, 16 );


        if( $action == 'e' ) {
            $output = base64_encode( openssl_encrypt( $string, $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv ) );
        }
        else if( $action == 'd' ){
            $output = openssl_decrypt( base64_decode( $string ), $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv );
        }

        return $output;
    }
```

The problem I now have is that I can't encrypt using the same algorithm using C#. Well I managed to encrypt something but it is not giving me the same output. Like I write : Test 123 test and both functions give different output. I'm new to encryption so...

For the C# function used :

```
        private const string AesIV256 = "thisismyiv_iv";
        private const string AesKey256 = "thisismykey_key";

        private string Encrypt256(string text)
        {
            // AesCryptoServiceProvider
            AesCryptoServiceProvider aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
            aes.BlockSize = 128;
            aes.KeySize = 256;


            aes.IV = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(AesIV256);
            var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(AesKey256);
            SHA256Managed hashString = new SHA256Managed();
            var hashValue = hashString.ComputeHash(message);
            
            aes.Key = hashValue;
            aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            //aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

            // Convert string to byte array
            byte[] src = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(text);

            // encryption
            using (ICryptoTransform encrypt = aes.CreateEncryptor())
            {
                byte[] dest = encrypt.TransformFinalBlock(src, 0, src.Length);

                // Convert byte array to Base64 strings
                return Convert.ToBase64String(dest);
            }
        }
```

Comment: This PHP code has several vulnerabilities/flaws. I would recommend fixing this code before you start the C# port. The already encrypted data is probably not very securely encrypted.

Comment: I understand. But the encryption is more like a deterrent. It is not extremely sensitive informations like passwords etc. It's basically a customer list and it is encrypted just in case a local rival company would get their hands on our server. Which is really unlikely. I plan to change the encryption eventually but for now, it is not required...

Comment: On PHP-side you get the 16 bytes long IV from a substring of the sha256-hashed "$secret_iv". This should be done on C# side as well (now you just UTF8-decode the string to a byte array.

Comment: Yes Thanks! I saw that. I hashed in sha256 the IV and then took the first 16bytes. But still my output is different

Comment: Apart from the IV (see Michael Fehr's comment)  there are also these differences: Double Base64 encoding of the ciphertext in the PHP code, single Base64 encoding in the C# code. Derivation of the key/IV with SHA256, where the hash in the PHP code is a hexadecimal encoded string, but binary in the C# code. Encoding of the data in the C# code with Unicode (which corresponds to UTF-16LE). For completeness: A static IV and SHA256 as password based key derivation function are insecure.

Comment: Okay Thanks y'all for your answers! I found a tutorial for both PHP and C# online on another way to encrypt / decrypt. So I guess I'll just decrypt all my data and re-encrypt it using this new algorithm.